# Asyncio and RabbitMQ: How to know if more messages are awaiting from RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, python-asyncio

How do I know in the callback-method if asyncio has received more messages from RabbitMQ that are left for me to process?

I'm receiving a batch of messages from RabbitMQ simultaneously. I need to process them and then send message to another service once I've most likely received the batch. I could do this with a async timer but it would be simpler just to check if asyncio has another message for me from RabbitMQ.

I'm currently using the aio-pika library. The code looks like this:

```
async def subscribe_to_messages():
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
        host=host, port=port, virtualhost=virtualhost, login=login, password=password
    )
    channel = await connection.channel()
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, auto_delete=True)
    await queue.bind(exchange=queue_ex_name, routing_key=queue_routing_key)

    await queue.consume(callback=process_message, consumer_tag='my_tag')    


async def process_message(msg): 
    # Process the message

    # How do I know here if asyncio already has received another message for me? 
    # Once I've received all messages for now, I will need to 
    # send a message to another service.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, just calling `queue.consume` will already call the callback function once for each received message - no need to worry about that.

You just have to write a function that will process the contents of a single message - if there are other messages waiting, it will be imediatelly called again with the next message -

Trying to check the queue from within the message, not only would complicate your function, as you could get into a lot of corner cases on double-handling certain messages (say, your function peek the next message from the queue, process it, returns, and is called again with the message it just processed)

https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rabbitmq-tutorial/6-rpc.html#callback-queue

(note the code comment which says "start processing queue").

The  "await queue.consume" call basically will not return until the queue is closed by some external event or an exception takes place.

Comment: I'm aware of this @jsbueno. I've changed my post to clarify why I need to know if more messages are coming and what I intend to do with that fact.